# how to out put woo commerce add to cart button in my own custom product-single.php page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

my problem is that i am using my own custom single-product.php page and its working as i am wanting because i have used loop to show single product contents according to mine needs ... 
but no the only issue i an facing is that i could not get "add to cart" button code any where there ? and now my add to cart button is missing that made me totally unable to add product to cart ...
here is mine complete code `<div class="shop-info">
                <?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => product, 'posts_per_page' => 1) ); ?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <h2>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>
                <span class="check"></span>
                <span class="stock">IN STOCK</span>
                        <span class="right-code">
                            <span class="code">CODE: </span>
                            <span class="number"><?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?></span>
                        </span>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/shop-line.png" alt=""/>
                <span class="price">$<?php $product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );
                    echo $price = $product->price; ?></span>
                <span class="total">QUANTITY: </span>
                        <span class="select">
                            <a href="">00</a>
                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                        </span>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/shop-line.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="product-single-content">
                    <p class="product-detail">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="add-buttons">
                    <a class="add-to-cart" href="<?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?>">ADD TO BASKET/ BORROW</a>
                    <a class="add-to-cart pink" href="">ADD TO WISH LIST</a>
                </div>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <ul class="social-networks">
                        <li><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a class="twitter" href="#">twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a class="play" href="#">play</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </div>`
in code above and in div class button's section my own buttons as anchors named as "ADD TO BASKET/BORROW" placed and i want once that anchor is clicked this item should be added to cart ... any one there to help me out of this please ... ??? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

`<a class="add-to-cart" href="<?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?>">ADD TO BASKET/ BORROW</a>`

with

`<?php do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'); ?>`

And if you want to change add to cart text then add below code to your theme's `functions.php` :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'your_custom_cart_button_text' );

function your_custom_cart_button_text(){
    return __( 'ADD TO BASKET/ BORROW', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

**NOTE:** It won't add for the variable products.

Comment: yes dear i tried that one and it shows add to cart button and on click it posts form data to some other page ... now the issue is that i dont know where that page goes ? i mean is that added to cart or not ? because it did not shown any useful message to me ... how to show a message now ? once clicked on button and added to cart how can i show that "added to cart" and then there may be a new button shown like view cart ... to view cart ... as woocommerce actually do for us ...

Comment: Akram, were you able to find a solution to this? I need to create a very custom single product template but it's getting too complicated :(